# How to avoid a page break between paragraph number and the paragraph itself?

Tags: html, page-break-inside

I'm generating PDF documents based on HTML content and I'm struggling with a page break issue. I have a document with many paragraphs, using numbered lists. These work just fine, unless it is a multiline paragraph that extends beyond the end of the page.

In that case **only** the paragraph number stays on the current page, and the **entire** text of the paragraph shifts to the next page.

I would like to either shift number and all text to the next page - **or** - show the first line of the text on the current page. In other words, always keep paragraph number and text together.

I tried putting section or div tags around the list item and use `break-inside: avoid`, but that did not seem to have any effect.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") ". ";
  width: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

section {
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<b>Summary of the challenge</b>
<ol>
  <li>
    A paragraph with a single line of text works fine.
  </li>

  <section>
    <li>
      A multiline paragraph will break between the number and the text.
    </li>
  </section>
</ol>

</html>
```